# A book about looking for a river mouth

Tags: story-identification, novel

There was a book that was read to me when I was a child. Probably in the region of 20 years now, so please forgive the vague information.

All I can remember about it was that it was set in a world that was very heavily drought ridden. I think there were legends about a river, or a river mouth. As in a part of the world where there was still water. And I recall there being lion-people. The cover on my copy illustrated them as humans with lions heads.

I know that it was divided into chapters and I do not think that it was illustrated apart from the cover.

I have been trying to remember the title for many years now. Does anybody else recognise this story? Does anybody know the title.

Comment: What country and language did you read it in? Was it from a school or library? Was it intended for kids or adults?

Comment: @A. M. Neville, The big problem comes in with the fact that I didn't read it. I was 6 y/o at most and could barely read for myself, my mother read it to me. She is a HS English teacher, and I have this idea in the back of my mind that she got it from the school book room, so maybe it was aimed at low highschool kids (13 - 15 y/o). Certainly most of the books she read to me were aimed more at the 9 - 14 age bracket than my own.

I am South African, and my copy was in English, but I could not say if that was a translation or not.

Comment: To the person who voted to close this: surely "humans with lion heads" is enough to qualify it as fantasy?

Comment: I have just remembered something else, and I can't believe I forgot it. The major plot device it about some children who have been told the legends about the river. They leave home (I think they actually run away) to find it, following the dry river bed upstream. Somehow they encounter the lion-people.